# OpenCV - RGB to HSV and back to RGB?

Tags: opencv, rgb, hsv

I have an image that i want to convert from RGB to HSV, and then back to RGB.

This is how i do it:

```
Mat frame1, frame2, frame3;
cvtColor(frame1, frame2, CV_RGB2HSV);
cvtColor(frame2, frame3, CV_HSV2BGR);
namedWindow("origin", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
namedWindow("rgb2hsv", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
namedWindow("hsv2rgb", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
imshow("origin", frame1);
imshow("rgb2hsv", frame2);
imshow("hsv2rgb", frame3);
```

I believe i get the correct result when i convert from RGB to HSV.
However, when i convert that converted image back to RGB, it gives me an incorrect result.

Any idea why? 
Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
cvtColor(frame1, frame2, CV_RGB2HSV);
cvtColor(frame2, frame3, CV_HSV2BGR);
```

should be (notice it is BGR2HSV instead of RGB2HSV)

```
cvtColor(frame1, frame2, CV_BGR2HSV);
cvtColor(frame2, frame3, CV_HSV2BGR);
```

Comment: true! that's awkward can't believe i didn't notice.. thanks!